# How can I connect PopSQL with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, popsql

I am facing some problems to connect popsql with mysql.

I am not sure that I be using the correct port:

[image]

when I use this command in the terminal:  agustinleira$ netstat -nap tcp | grep -i "listen"

I see this ports:

[image]

Why I can't connect to mysql?

Maybe because I am connecting to mongo in this port?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved, the port correct is 3306 for mysql.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).